# buttons cant be styled in css

Tags: html, jquery, css

Here are my buttons:

```
<body>
<form name="form1">
            <span id="buttons">
                <input type="button" name="button1" value="6"/>
                <input type="button" name="button2" value="4"/>
                <input type="button" name="button3" value="2"/>
            </span>
        </form>>
</body>
```

I cant for the life of me get them to be styled in css, I just dont know their identifier?
currently I'm using

```
<style>
    #buttons {
        "css style is here"
    }
```

and that looks REALLY BAD
another method I tried was

```
    <style>
        input[type="button"] {
            "css style is here"
            }
```

which is exactly what I wanted, BUT absolute positioning made them all bunch up in the exact same space and I found no way to separate them.
I need either a way to clasify them and style them seperatly OR to space them when using the second method

"sidenote" Here's the css styling I used that caused them to bunch up:

```
<style>
     input[type="button"] {
        background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #44c767 5%, #05aaf7 100%);
            display:inline-block;
            border-radius:6px;
            border:0px solid #83c41a;
            cursor:pointer;
            color:#ffffff;
            font-family:Arial;
            font-size:17px;
            padding:16px 31px;
            text-decoration:none;
            text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
            position:absolute;
            left: 45%;
            top: 30%;
          }
     </style>
```

Comment: you missed the important information which the CSS your are using. *"css style is here"* will not help us help you

Comment: Its not the css style that I want
I cant get each button styled diffrently

Comment: you said *absolute positioning made them all bunch up in the exact same space and I found no way to separate them* which clearly indicate that you are not styling your element correctly that's why we need to see how your are doing so we can correct you.

Comment: aight Ill add it

Comment: remove `position:absolute;
            left: 45%;
            top: 30%;` and use margin to adjust the position

Comment: ok, ill try that, also any way for me to make them more spaced out? I want more individual control

Comment: When you make them all with `position:absolute; left: 45%; top: 30%;` they end up in the same place because you tell them to do so. 
If you want to keep absolute styling, you can give them each separate class and specify top and left for each one. You can read more about absolute positioning here: [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: One last thing: Just add this bellow as an actual answer so if people do make my mistake it wont happen again

Comment: also its going bonkers and they're spaced too far apart now